# Salary R&D laboratory Oil Industry Netherlands with a PhD (UK) and experience

Tags: netherlands, salary

I am currently contemplating a job opportunity in the Netherlands, working for an oil service company in their R&D labs. I have a PhD in petroleum engineering, 2 years of relevant and one year of other engineering experience. I don't speak any Dutch.

I was wondering what should I ask as my expected salary?

I'm currently working in academia and the pay is not really in the scale of the oil industry, but I don't know much about the Netherlands and also it is a Downturn in the industry, hence my struggle!

Comment: Did you search about average salaries for oil and gas industry in the  Netherlands?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about pay expectations in a specific industry and not about expat life. I also deem it primarily opinion based and unclear without the unavailable knowledge about the position and the candidate - and even with that knowledge impossible to answer in a definite way.

Comment: Eugen, Yes, but data is quite limited for the Netherlands. Also the data are almost all from the pre-crash, hence I'm looking based on the expat experiences. Any extrapolation from other industries would also be appreciated.